# How to create a regplot in Pyspark - tough time with sparse vector

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, linear-regression, sparse-vector

I am using a Colab Notebook and doing a linear regression in Pyspark.
I completed the whole regression with no problems. However, we were asked to add a regression plot, and that's where I am stuck.

I had multiple features in my dataset which I clubbed into one column using the feature assembler. Here is what my predicted dataset looks like:

[image: predicted dataset]

I now want to create something like this:

[image: Regplot]

And I am using the following code:

```
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
x = mdata.toPandas()['Independent_Features'].values.tolist()
y = mdata.toPandas()['MonthlyCharges'].values.tolist()
y_pred=mdata.toPandas()['prediction'].values.tolist()
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        mode='markers',
        name='Original_Data',
    ))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=y_pred,
        name='Predicted'
    ))
fig.update_layout(
    title="Linear Regression",
    xaxis_title="Independent Features",
    yaxis_title="Monthly Charges",
    font=dict(
        family="Courier New, monospace",
        size=18,
        color="#7f7f7f"
    )
)


fig.show()
```

But I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-cb270db7e5d4> in <module>()
     30 
     31 
---> 32 fig.show()

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in show(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3396         import plotly.io as pio
   3397 
-> 3398         return pio.show(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3399 
   3400     def to_json(self, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/plotly/io/_renderers.py in show(fig, renderer, validate, **kwargs)
    387 
    388     # Mimetype renderers
--> 389     bundle = renderers._build_mime_bundle(fig_dict, renderers_string=renderer, **kwargs)
    390     if bundle:
    391         if not ipython_display:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/plotly/io/_renderers.py in _build_mime_bundle(self, fig_dict, renderers_string, **kwargs)
    295                         setattr(renderer, k, v)
    296 
--> 297                 bundle.update(renderer.to_mimebundle(fig_dict))
    298 
    299         return bundle

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/plotly/io/_base_renderers.py in to_mimebundle(self, fig_dict)
    389             default_width="100%",
    390             default_height=525,
--> 391             validate=False,
    392         )
    393 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/plotly/io/_html.py in to_html(fig, config, auto_play, include_plotlyjs, include_mathjax, post_script, full_html, animation_opts, default_width, default_height, validate, div_id)
    144 
    145     # ## Serialize figure ##
--> 146     jdata = to_json_plotly(fig_dict.get("data", []))
    147     jlayout = to_json_plotly(fig_dict.get("layout", {}))
    148 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/plotly/io/_json.py in to_json_plotly(plotly_object, pretty, engine)
    122         from _plotly_utils.utils import PlotlyJSONEncoder
    123 
--> 124         return json.dumps(plotly_object, cls=PlotlyJSONEncoder, **opts)
    125     elif engine == "orjson":
    126         JsonConfig.validate_orjson()

/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    236         check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,
    237         separators=separators, default=default, sort_keys=sort_keys,
--> 238         **kw).encode(obj)
    239 
    240 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/_plotly_utils/utils.py in encode(self, o)
     57         """
     58         # this will raise errors in a normal-expected way
---> 59         encoded_o = super(PlotlyJSONEncoder, self).encode(o)
     60         # Brute force guessing whether NaN or Infinity values are in the string
     61         # We catch false positive cases (e.g. strings such as titles, labels etc.)

/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py in encode(self, o)
    197         # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
    198         # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
--> 199         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    200         if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
    201             chunks = list(chunks)

/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py in iterencode(self, o, _one_shot)
    255                 self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
    256                 self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
--> 257         return _iterencode(o, 0)
    258 
    259 def _make_iterencode(markers, _default, _encoder, _indent, _floatstr,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/_plotly_utils/utils.py in default(self, obj)
    134             except NotEncodable:
    135                 pass
--> 136         return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
    137 
    138     @staticmethod

/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py in default(self, o)
    177 
    178         """
--> 179         raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
    180                         f'is not JSON serializable')
    181 

TypeError: Object of type SparseVector is not JSON serializable
```

Here is a link to the notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NLibPkZgOE_w7dVTerAF4nUQiPXW_o06?usp=sharing

I saw it mentioned SparseVector, so I tried to convert it to a DenseVector, but that just wouldn't work, tried multiple commands, but nothing helps.

Comment: Could you share this notebook?

Comment: Also, please post your code as *text* so we can use your code to test easier, without typing everything again.

Comment: Sure, Here is a link to the notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NLibPkZgOE_w7dVTerAF4nUQiPXW_o06?usp=sharing

Comment: And here is a link to the code that i am trying to use for the regplot:   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-FoQmH8RnNygynnzyqVIFpQRrPojiiUB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can edit the post [using this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73180403/edit). A code formatting device is provided in the editor (paste the code, select it, click the code button). Ping me when the post is edited, I will try to help you reopen it.

Comment: @halfer I have added my code.

Comment: OK, voting to reopen. Could you also replace the image of the error with the text equivalent? That can be rendered as code in the same way.

Comment: @halfer I have added the text of the error.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) Can you share your data as text we can copy/paste please?

Comment: @tripleee ... could you please let me know how to share the data. The data has about 7000 rows.

Comment: You'll want to pare it down to a [mre] similar to the data you posted in the image.